# ¿Cómo obtengo únicamente un texto a partir de un caracter?

Tags: java, string

(Uso readLine de BufferedReader para leer el txt completo que son varias lineas, pero almaceno linea por linea, me interesa trabajar así.)(Claramente lo único que me interesa es el texto en ingles, lo que pasa que la longitud de la linea o numero de caracteres puede variar, por eso lo importante es el "|", que siempre está)

Entonces tengo un "String Temporal" con ese texto... únicamente me interesa el texto que viene después del "|", ¿qué debo implementar para obtener únicamente lo que viene después del | y hasta el final de la linea o string sin todo lo demás?.

Aclaro que soy usuario Beginner en Java, por favor lo mas sencillo que se pueda hacer?

Gracias

P.D: Tengo esto:

```
public String leerTxt(String direccion){ //direccion del archivo

    String texto = "";

    try{
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion));
        String temp = "";
        String bfRead;

        while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null){ 
            //haz el ciclo, mientras bfRead tiene datos

            temp = temp + "\n" + bfRead; //guardado el texto del archivo
        }

        texto = temp;
```

Comment: Utiliza el método `indexOf()` para buscar la posición de ese caracter y luego `substring()`.

Comment: Hola @Tefa, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: lo resolví usando indexOf() y substring() tal como @E. Betanzos sugirio.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas solucionado. Una actualización con la solución no estaría mal. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví usando indexOf() y substring() tal como @E. Betanzos sugirió.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion));
            String temp = "";
            String bfRead;
            String charDiv = "|";
            int posChar;
            String textATrad;


            while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null){ 
                //haz el ciclo, mientras bfRead tiene datos
                posChar = bfRead.indexOf(charDiv);
                if (posChar != -1)
                {
                    textATrad = bfRead.substring(posChar+1, bfRead.length());
                    temp = temp + "\n" + textATrad; //guardado el texto del archivo
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = temp + "\n";                    
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues yo utilizaría el método `split()` perteneciente a `java.lang.String`, el cual nos permite dividir una cadena.
Ejemplo de uso..

```
public class StringTemporal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temporal = "05.mkd.2@124@m-mis-2@Я сейчас немного занята, так что, "
                + "предлагаю сразу перейти к делу. Катюша описала в "
                + "общих чертах суть проблемы.|I'm in a middle of something, so how about we get straight to the "
                + "chase? My Kate has told me the gist of your problem.";
        String[] partes = temporal.split("\\|");
        System.out.println("Después de | tenemos: "+ partes[1]);
    }
}
```

Y nos devolvería por consola..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En el ejemplo partimos la cadena por donde tenemos **`|`** mediante una expresión regular.

Comment: Solo me funciona si el txt tiene el texto que les compartí... si el texto tiene 300 renglones mas, ya no funciona.
Si bien mi código lee el texto y salta una linea por cada final de linea, no puede separar esa parte que lee guardar y continuar de la manera que esta programado aparentemente, alguna ayuda? Gracias por lo brindado por supuesto.
Acá adjunto una imagen del contenido del txt: (https://i.imgur.com/HoiHS7l.png)

Sin el código que me compartes, mi programa copia todo el txt respetando todo, lo cual funciona, con él no; pero obviamente quiero solo lo de ingles.

Comment: Cada cuanto se repite el `|`, una vez por renglón.??

Comment: Solo una vez por renglón. pero son varios, ahí podes ver el txt. (en block de notas tiene activado el modo `Ajuste de Linea` para la foto. Por lo que si ves mas de 2 lineas para un texto, en realidad esta en una sola.

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a tu duda, de como recuperar la parte del String después del símbolo '|' se puede solucionar utilizando el método **split** de Java, el cuál divide la cadena de acuerdo al parámetro que le indiques, por lo tanto una posible solución sería así:

```
 while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null){ 
        //haz el ciclo, mientras bfRead tiene datos

        String [] parts = bfRead.split("|"); // se almacena en un array
        String part2 = parts[1]; // deseas recuperar después del '|' por lo 
                                 //tanto posición [1] del array
        temp = temp + "\n" + part2; //guardado el texto del archivo
    }
```

Saludos!

Comment: Solo me funciona si el txt tiene el texto que les compartí... si el texto tiene 300 renglones mas, ya no funciona.
Si bien mi código lee el texto y salta una linea por cada final de linea, no puede separar esa parte que lee guardar y continuar de la manera que esta programado aparentemente, alguna ayuda? Gracias por lo brindado por supuesto.
Acá adjunto una imagen del contenido del txt: (https://i.imgur.com/HoiHS7l.png)

Sin el código que me compartes, mi programa copia todo el txt respetando todo, lo cual funciona, con él no; pero obviamente quiero solo lo de ingles.